# How to integrate several SPARQL queries

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

This query:

```
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.data.gov/semantic/data/alpha/1458/dataset-1458.rdf#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dgtwc: <http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/2009/data-gov-twc.rdf#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
SELECT ?chem 
FROM <http://ontomatica.com/public/ontologies/dataset-1458.rdf>
WHERE {
    ?s dgtwc:uses_property ?chem .
    FILTER (regex(STR(?chem), '.*sel.*')) .
}
```

produces this [result](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=%09PREFIX%20pizza%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.data.gov%2Fsemantic%2Fdata%2Falpha%2F1458%2Fdataset-1458.rdf%23%3E%0D%0A%09PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%09PREFIX%20dgtwc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata-gov.tw.rpi.edu%2F2009%2Fdata-gov-twc.rdf%23%3E%0D%0A%09PREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%20%0D%0A%09SELECT%20%3Fchem%20%0D%0A%09FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fontomatica.com%2Fpublic%2Fontologies%2Fdataset-1458.rdf%3E%0D%0A%09WHERE%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Fs%20dgtwc%3Auses_property%20%3Fchem%20.%0D%0A%09%09FILTER%20%28regex%28STR%28%3Fchem%29%2C%20%27.*sel.*%27%29%29%20.%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl)

This query:

```
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.data.gov/semantic/data/alpha/1458/dataset-1458.rdf#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?method
FROM <http://ontomatica.com/public/ontologies/dataset-1458.rdf>
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label ?method
    FILTER regex(?method, 'selenium', 'i')
    }
```

produces this [result](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=%09PREFIX%20pizza%3A%09%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.data.gov%2Fsemantic%2Fdata%2Falpha%2F1458%2Fdataset-1458.rdf%23%3E%0D%0A%09PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%09%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%09SELECT%20%3Fmethod%0D%0A%09FROM%09%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fontomatica.com%2Fpublic%2Fontologies%2Fdataset-1458.rdf%3E%0D%0A%09WHERE%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fmethod%0D%0A%09%09FILTER%20regex%28%3Fmethod%2C%20%27selenium%27%2C%20%27i%27%29%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl)

For `<rdf:Description rdf:about="#entry6483">`, how to write the query that would produce this result?

```
------------------------------------------------------
| chem           | method                 | selenium |
======================================================
| pizza:selenium | "Selenium (mcg/100 g)" | 9        |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give that you have the entryno "entry6483"

How about

```
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.data.gov/semantic/data/alpha/1458/dataset-1458.rdf#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dgtwc: <http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/2009/data-gov-twc.rdf#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?chem ?method ?selenium
FROM <http://ontomatica.com/public/ontologies/dataset-1458.rdf>
WHERE {

    pizza:entry6483 ?chem ?selenium .
    ?chem rdfs:label ?method .
    FILTER regex(?method, 'selenium', 'i')

}
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for!